# How to get RGB values of a transparent texel in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I put the mouse cursor on a transparent texel and check the Info panel, there is only the Alpha value displayed, but empty for RGB:

[image: Photoshop snapshot]

Comment: `"texel"` is a specific term in use in 3D modeling and texturing which refers to the base unit of resolution of a texture on the surface of a 3D mesh; in 2D rasterwork the equivalent term is `"pixel"` - thus when working in Photoshop one is working in pixels - if one takes a  2K (2048 x 2048) Photoshop file of seamlessly-tiled texture into a 3D DCC tool like Blender or Modo and applies it to several meshes, each with differing UV scales, you may then discuss the idea of `"texel density"` referring to how consistently that texture resolution is applied relative to object scales in your scene.

Comment: Take a look at this question / answer, https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/is-there-an-inverse-eraser-tool-on-photoshop you will get the RGB and the transparency objects.

Comment: @Rafael this won't work if a pixel is absolutely transparent

Comment: If a pixel is absolutely transparent there is a chance it is discarded from the layer, from the file. Some programs drop that info.

Comment: @Rafael I don't understand what you mean. Do you have an example of a program that keeps info of transparent pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Using a term `texel` doesn't make much sense in Photoshop: it's pixels. Photoshop doesn't keep color information for transparent pixels: a pixel needs to be at least 1/256 non-transparent to have any color information.

Sometimes you might see a color in the Info panel even if opacity is 0%: that's only because there's a slightly-non transparent pixel in there and it's transparently less than 0% in 0-100% integer scale (`1/256*100 = 0.39%`, Photoshop 'rounds' this to `0%`)

[image]

Comment: Yeap, sometimes the "king of raster programs" is a bit lame on its tools. U_U

Comment: @Rafael how so? What RGB value should a transparent pixel have?

Comment: Based on your comments, You are only considering an absolutely transparent pixel as transparent. Transparency can have one of 254 values.

Comment: my comments are based on OP's screenshot where he points on an absolutely transparent pixel and asks why it doesn't have any color

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it feels odd to me that Photoshop doesn't keep track of RGB values of fully transparent pixels, while the values indeed exist in a PNG file, and some other tools like Gimp ("Pointer Information" panel) just worked fine. RGB value matters to me because I'll be using this texture in 3D applications, and texture filtering and mipmapping (neither of them uses premultiplied alpha) make a huge difference if these transparent pixels are white or black.

Comment: @LeoM say you've made a circle with a b/w gradient on it. What colors will be assigned to transparent pixels in Gimp? Can you show an example?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Maybe I didn't make my point clear. By "worked fine", I mean Gimp precisely shows the RGB value of a certain pixel. If I open the same image with Gimp, it tells me (Red:100%,Green:100%,Blue:100%,Alpha:0%) when I'm pointing to a transparent pixel.

Comment: @LeoM This is what I don't understand: how having a transparent pixel with white will help you to get a clean mipmap with the example above (red stroke)? To my understanding you should have color bleed for that but what does it have to do with transparent pixels? Maybe you can add practical and less abstract examples?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy If the transparent pixels are black, there would be a dark outline surrounding the red stroke in the mipmaps generated by OpenGL. But if they are red, there would be no such artifacts. Anyway, all I wanted to do is check those transparent pixels' RGB values in Photoshop, set aside how to manipulate them or use them.

Comment: @LeoM but you wrote "If I open the same image with Gimp, it tells me (Red:100%,Green:100%,Blue:100%,Alpha:0%)" — it's white! where this red comes from if it was never there? What I'm saying is I think it's an issue of a particular asset pipeline, not PS.

Comment: You are wrong photoshop really keeps a color for the transparency! Ther is no such thing as transparent even 100% transparent pixels have a color. @SergeyKritskiy its just that Photoshop tries really really hard to make people not aware of this. Ist too much of a bother for graphic designers and unimportant. So it  is sort of a good thing. But sadly also this is why comp people could fix "color bleed" in 1990's when most graphic designers had huge problems with this.

Comment: And yes this is really Photoshop's fault.

Answer (score 1):

You are right there is no such thing as a transparent pixel! All pixels have a color even fully transparent ones.

You can get this value, photoshop just uses a lot of energy to keep people thinking transparent is a color of its own. And for some reason 100% transparent is white by default in Photoshop, this makes PS sometimes a bit problematic for game assets. Anybody who interpolates values knows differently*. There are essentially 2 ways, and any combo thereof.

1. The image calculations is impervious to Photoshop's sleigh of hand. This is useful if you want to decompose the channels as they are and move over to channel based workflow at some point (see below).
2. Scripting layer has access to the actual data of a pixel

Now there is a lesser known mode in Photoshop, back to 1980's. Does not work well with layers but solves this issue (clunky) with channels. All you see is the opaque values and lapha is taken form channel called alpha. So if you really need to color the transparent pixels do this:

Just copy the red channel over to a new channel, green abd blue also then alpha as separate. Delete layers and make the new channels the R G B channel and copy alpha as a channel named alpha. You will miss all photoshop's functions but you can do this as a last step, or last resort. You can decode this as an action so you only ever have to do this once.

Photoshop essentially is a bad editor for non-image work. A lot of other tools are way better. Anybody who does vfx will has to stand where you are now, at some point.

* One can debate wether this is good or bad. Lets just say this is the way they have chosen to implement this. Its ok if you only ever do images for print, ist semi ok if you only do images for 1:1 size display in digital. It can be problematic, but in 3d and vfx its a severe limitation. It has the benefit of needing a lower amount of brainpower to accept.

Comment: Is the result not the same as this https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/is-there-an-inverse-eraser-tool-on-photoshop?

Comment: Could you upload a practical example of where this matters? What you've described with channels, this will make white where transparency is, how is this beneficial for mipmapping or anything else? To my understanding a compressor dictates if fully transparent pixels will be treated as white or black and it's user's role to add bleeding.

Comment: @Rafael yes but calculations would work on multilayer files.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy two main issues premultiplied vs unmultiplied alpha since 3D engines mainly require unmultplied alpha youd need to unmultiply the color. Second when you work out the mipmap the white will bleed trough to the mipmap generator. Unless you build a more sophisticated builder, which then would need a switch somewhere (source of error) to account for all those textures that dont use alpha channel as alpha but a extra datalayer.

Comment: @joojaa as you mentioned, if no color was set, the color will be defined as white. So if a color was never set, you'll have the same issues with bleeding of white. So it's up to the assets artist to make sure there's a correct color bleeding in the asset. No? I think I've seen a plugin for Photoshop that was exporting PNGs with a bleeding in transparency similar to what 3d software does for UVs... but! this is only needed on the last stage, during the export, there's no need for this in Photoshop if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy No i said Photoshop makes the color white, this is possibly the wrong thing to do. There are lots of other applications that do not do this! So you would save a lot fo time if you didn't use Photoshop as there is no need to do work 2 times. No asset maker has time to draws each image 16 times just to get the right color they would never survive with the workload. Or like mostly happens is their quality would suffer. But this is really no concern for graphic designers, but know that computer graphics people co invented making graphics and they did in fact also solve this issue.

Comment: So if my image started of as red. And i masked it off and flattened the image then PS made it white. Now VFX people know of this they call this pre-multiplied matte, whic can be handy. But the weird thing is photoshop uses straight matte except for 100% transparent pixels. Getting the worst of both worlds, because now the semitransparent pixels are fully red but the 100% is white...

Comment: @joojaa thank you for explanation. That's why I was curious to see an example of a workflow with a png for assets in a different app. hen I was working on that one game that has issues with PNGs from Photoshop, artists simply used a different export to generate proper colors for transparency: there was no need to draw each image 16 times...

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy it does not necessarily happen. For it to cause big problems you need to observe your textures form afar. It is especially a problem for shaders that need to blur the texture in the shader code like bump mapping and so on. Yet you used to see these artifacts in indie games quite often. But never in AAA games, mainly because they dont use Photoshop to make textures. Since blender has become ok with texturing and other sculpting/3dpainting workflows have become common you have seen a remarkable increase in quality of shader textures

Answer (score 0):

- Duplicate the layer until you have 100% opacity *(to be faster,
  duplicate in 2 times, then all of them 2 times, then all of them 2
  more times, and so on)*.
- Eyedropper in the opaque layer.