# How can i remove transparent pixels between two layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I merged two layers to create an image but when I merged two layers there are[image] transparent pixels between the layers. How can I remove those transparent pixels?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an "inverse eraser" tool on Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/is-there-an-inverse-eraser-tool-on-photoshop)

Comment: Here is one related question, in case you do not have the source material. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97458/is-there-an-inverse-eraser-tool-on-photoshop

Answer (score 1):

You do only have one layer. If you want to remove the transparency between the two rectangles you can use the fill tool to colour the gap. Or the probably better way is to add a colour layer below the current layer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gap between the two layers,so when you merged the layers,the gap in the middle cannot disappear.You can go back to the previous step ang readjust the positon of layers.Let them get closer.If you can't go back,you can use the selection tool to select the color above and move it.